# Google Maps SDK iOS map update location rendering issue

Tags: swift, uikit, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am facing an issue with the Google Maps SDK for iOS rendering update location glitch after a map update. Whenever the map updates its blue point (current location), the marker starts to exhibit strange behavior. Instead of smoothly transitioning to the new location, the marker sometimes jumps to incorrect positions or flickers rapidly between the old and new locations.

I have verified that the issue is not related to my location data or the logic for updating the map. It seems to be an internal rendering issue within the Google Maps SDK itself. This glitch is negatively impacting the user experience of my app, as the location marker is a crucial component for my users.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Initialize a Google Maps view in an iOS app.
2. Set the map view location enable to true as this

```
   self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
```

3. Implement logic to update the map's region or zoom level.
4. Observe the behavior of the location marker during and after the map update and GPS.

Check here a video of the case:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D0LgTTpUaeMxJzML5vmgjETpLfQzsd18/view

From here you can download a sample project:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ecTVERplUe0cLlrcQEH5IE0QjT3VBod3/view?usp=share_link

Codes:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let mapView: GMSMapView = {
        let mapView = GMSMapView(frame: .zero)
        return mapView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        self.view = mapView
    }
}
```

Expected Behavior:
The location marker smoothly transitions to the new location as the map updates its region or zoom level.

Actual Behavior:
The location marker exhibits glitches such as jumping to incorrect positions or flickering rapidly during and after the map update.

Environment:

- Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 8.0.1
- Xcode version: 14.3
- iOS version: 16.6

I have already tried the following:

- Verifying my location data and map update logic, which seem to be correct.
- Experimenting with different configurations and options of the Google Maps SDK.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? Any insights into what might be causing this glitch and how to work around it would be greatly appreciated. If there are any known solutions, code examples, or suggestions for troubleshooting, please share them.

Thank you for your help in advance!

**The tried solutions but not solved the issue
**

- Update the Google Maps SDK library to the newest version.
- Added the update location function in a background thread instead of the main thread.
- I created a new screen with a basic implementation of Google Map SDK and run the GPS simulator and I face the same issue.

Comment: I have checked project that you have shared and when I click on current location it can't go any where, but when I use your location (ridah-to-airport) and check that file it is giving multiple locations don't use it and use current location then hopefully it will solve your problem

Comment: Based on the provided video, it's evident that there is an issue with the movement tracking at the specified location. The video clearly demonstrates a rendering glitch that occurs consistently. To validate this concern, I meticulously tested the updated location using the provided simulator GPX file (Riyadh-to-airport), as well as through an actual car ride. Strikingly, the problem persisted across both scenarios, confirming the existence of the issue.

Comment: you need to update location after few meter and update location then it will naviage like Uber

Comment: The issue that I'm facing is clear in the provided video, the current location marker(blue dot) is jumping to incorrect positions or flickering rapidly while moving on street.